# Overfull vbox with scrletter

Tags: warnings, scrlttr2, bad-box

I have an overfull vbox in the header of a letter which I would like to suppress. Following mwe:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
%\vfuzz=15pt
\KOMAoptions{
  fromalign = right,
  fromemail = true,
  frommobilephone = true,
  fromphone = true,
  fromurl = true,
  backaddress = underlined,
}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{ich}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{irgendwo\\mehrzeilig\\stadt}
\begin{letter}{Vorname Nachname\\Position\\Firma\\Strasse}

\opening{Hallo,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The from address and the to address overlap a bit, thus I get an overfull vbox (and additionally a scrletter warning about it). I know I can suppress the compiler notice about the overfull vbox with `vfuzz` like in line 3. But I still have the scrletter warning.

Is there an `vfuzz`-equivalent in koma script?

I know I could simply ignore the message, the output is the same, but I don't want to miss other maybe more important warnings later on because of that.

thanks for helping!

EDIT: the answer below from esdd works, but if possible I would prefer a solution without patching koma-script macros due to the danger esdd mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of patching an internal command like in [my other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461387/43317) you can rebuild the header of the first page using the variable `firsthead`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox[t][2\baselineskip][t]{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
    \raggedleft\usekomafont{fromaddress}
    {\usekomafont{fromname}\usekomavar{fromname}}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}%
    \ifkomavarempty{fromphone}{}
      {\\\usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}}
    \ifkomavarempty{frommobilephone}{}
      {\\\usekomavar*{frommobilephone}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}}%
    \ifkomavarempty{fromemail}{}
      {\\\usekomavar*{fromemail}\usekomavar{fromemail}}%
    \ifkomavarempty{fromurl}{}
      {\\\usekomavar*{fromurl}\usekomavar{fromurl}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{ich}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{irgendwo\\mehrzeilig\\stadt}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{1234}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{5678}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{ich@wir.xxx}
\setkomavar{fromurl}{wir.xxx}

\begin{letter}{Vorname Nachname\\Position\\Firma\\Strasse}

\opening{Hallo,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

But you could also change the layout of the letter page. Maybe you reduce informations in the head and put them in the foot using variable `firstfoot`. Or you can place the from-information in the location field changing option `fromalign=right` to

```
fromalign=locationright
```

[image]

Or you can change the fontsize using

```
\addtokomafont{fromname}{\footnotesize}
\addtokomafont{fromaddress}{\footnotesize}
```

[image]

Comment: `fromalign=locationright` is the best solution for me. I originally changed `firstheadvpos` anyway, so now I just changed the `locvpos` and it looks the same, without warnings and without much patching/redefining. thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: It is not recommended to patch internal KOMA-Script commands. Such patches can break in the future.

With current KOMA-Script versions you can avoid the warnings regarding the height of your first head using

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% warning: patching an internal KOMA-Script command is not recommended- it could break in the future
\xpatchcmd{\@savevbox}
  {\addtolength{\@tempdimb}{\dp0}}
  {%
    \addtolength{\@tempdimb}{\dp0}%
    \ifstr{#5}{firstheadvpos}
      {\addtolength{\@tempdimb}{-15pt}}% <- adjust the length to your needs
      {}%
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% warning: patching an internal KOMA-Script command is not recommended- it could break in the future
\xpatchcmd{\@savevbox}
  {\addtolength{\@tempdimb}{\dp0}}
  {%
    \addtolength{\@tempdimb}{\dp0}%
    \ifstr{#5}{firstheadvpos}
      {\addtolength{\@tempdimb}{-15pt}}% <- adjust the length to your needs
      {}%
  }
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\KOMAoptions{
  fromalign = right,
  fromemail = true,
  frommobilephone = true,
  fromphone = true,
  fromurl = true,
  backaddress = underlined,
}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{ich}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{irgendwo\\mehrzeilig\\stadt}
\begin{letter}{Vorname Nachname\\Position\\Firma\\Strasse}

\opening{Hallo,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me, but I am aware of the danger with patching koma-script macros. Maybe I rather live without it or I end up breaking more than it helps.